# resizing image with gd or imagick so that it cover its transparent part

Tags: php, gd, image-resizing, imagick

I have an image customizing plugin having stage of 1000x700 where user can upload his/her pic and design it with in stage area.

Now if user doesn't use full staging area and use only some part of stage let say 800x400. My final image will be of 1000x700 with transparent background having user's design in middle of it.

Now question is, I want to stretch user design on full canvas with out white background.

How can I do this using php GD or imagick (not manually)?

Answer (score 0):

```
    $dstImage = imagecreatetruecolor(1000, 700);
    $black = imagecolorallocate($dstImage, 0, 0, 0);

    // Make the background transparent
    imagecolortransparent($dstImage, $black);

    $srcImage = imagecreatefrompng('srcImg.png');
    imagecopymerge($dstImage, $srcImage, 0, 0, 0, 800, 400, 1000, 700);
    imagepng($dstImage, 'outputNewImg.png');
```